# How to handle postback in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So i have made a partialview where users can sign in.

But when i submit forms i regular views i get an error 
"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

This i because my [HttpPost] controller action in the controller that handles the partial view redirects and thats a NoGo apparently.

I dont get the error when a user logs in. To clarify when the button in the partial view is pressed there is no problem.

The reason for puting the login in a Partialview is because a user should be able sign in from any page in the application

Here Is the code:

```
Controller for partialview Credentials:

public ActionResult Identify() {
        if(Session["User"] != null) {
            return PartialView("Identified", Session["User"]);
        } else {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Identify(Login login) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            Authenticate(login.LoginName, login.LoginPasscode);
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
    }


@model ViewModels.Login

@using(Html.BeginForm("Identify", "Credentials")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName)

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)

            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log Ind" />

    </div>
```

}

I have added the partial view by using the following line in _Layout

```
    @{Html.RenderAction("Identify", "Credentials");}
```

HomeController:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        db.Role.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string Foo) {
        db.Role.ToList();
        ViewBag.InTheBox = Foo;
        return View();
    }
```

and last home index view:

```
@if (ViewBag.InTheBox == null){
    ViewBag.InTheBox = "Nothing In Here";
}

<h1>@ViewBag.InTheBox</h1>    

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <input type="text" name="Foo"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**edit:**

So i figured out how to solve the problem and it was really simple. My overloaded method Identify should only have a httpget variant. The httppost variant of the method was renamed in this case to Authenticate and the form posts to that method. This resolved the problem. Correct code below.

```
Controller for partialview Credentials:

public ActionResult Identify() {
        if(Session["User"] != null) {
            return PartialView("Identified", Session["User"]);
        } else {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Authenticate(Login login) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            Authenticate(login.LoginName, login.LoginPasscode);
        }
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
    }


@model ViewModels.Login

@using(Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Credentials")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginName)

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoginPasscode)

            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log Ind" />

    </div>
```

}

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with razor but with a django MVC app I would have that type of logic exist inside of a masterpage that all pages inherit from.

Comment: I am not sure how to translate that to my particular problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RedirectToAcion(myActionName).
```

Comment: It does the same thing.

Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.